# In a talend job, how can I add a dependent jar file?

Tags: jar, talend

I want to make use of the utility methods from a jar file, in my talend job routines.  How can add this jar as dependent to my current job?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tLibraryLoad component - it lets you load a jar file so you can add it in the beginning of your job and the library will be available thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

tLoadLibrary will work, or you can also add dependencies to a job by right-clicking on the job in the repository too.